# DWT vs. FFT for BPM detection

Tags: fft, dwt

A BPM detection with FFT has been already [highlighted](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1112/detecting-drum-bpm-in-a-noisy-wav-file) on this site.

Would DWT do the job as well?

I've tried a Python [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42934754/4422958) using DWT but it seems that the output is wrong, that is for the first 10 seconds of these songs I get respectively:

- Blue Monday, New Order - 130 BPM
- Mighty Oaks, The Great Northwest - 155 BPM

What I want to know in context of this site, whether DWT is generally a wrong method to extract BPM and why.

Comment: there's many different wavelets. Whether or not the discrete wavelet transform does what you want depends on what you want and what wavelet you use. Generally "I heard method XYZ is cool, so I used it" isn't how engineering is done: describe the problem mathematically, describe the method mathematically, see whether they match.